# I made a calculator and want to store the sum to another cell using a button for saving the cell

Tags: google-sheets

When I get my sum I would like to save this to another cell say cell a1, then I would like to recalculate for a new sum and save the new sum to cell a2, I would like to keep doing this multiple times. The reason I want to do this is I want to track the total sum of one cell, after multiple calculations. I would like to avoid scripts if possible, but it seems like this might require a script.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the sum is in cell `D2`, try a function like this:

```
function appendResultToColumnA() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const targetRange = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
  const result = sheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
  const results = targetRange.getValues()
    .flat()
    .filter(String)
    .concat(result)
    .map(row => [row]);
  targetRange.offset(0, 0, results.length, 1)
    .setValues(results);
}
```

Then assign `appendResultToColumnA` to a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, Thank you. Only issue is I don't like to use stuff I don't understand, I got very basic knowledge in C# but I don't think that will help me understand what's going on here.

Comment: See the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).